Explanation as to why a Jump Game Problem doesnt work with Union Find Approach
I am trying to Solve a variation of Jump Game where the main point of the game is your given a 1D array of values, and a source value x which represents the starting index. Your objective is to see whether or not you can reach atleast one index i in the array such that arr[i] = 0; The only way you can traverse from a square is by moving i - arr[i] or i + arr[i] only if the value is still in array bounds (0 to arr.length - 1). (arr[i] is always positive)
Graph traversal algorithms which work backwards from a spot with value 0 to the source come to mind, but I was wondering if there is any explanation as to why Union Find wouldnt work. I thought UF would be perfect since there are only 2 squares max which are adjacent nodes, so if you iterate through the array and connect all adjacent nodes together, in theory I thought we can do a second pass through and see if we find any connected 0 nodes from the sourec, because after one pass through, all possible connections we can see form a node to its source should be satisfied so we have the final path though the array.
I implemented a Union Find algo, but I run into issues on larger test cases though I am finding it hard to visualize a case where it wouldnt work. Any mathematical explanation as to why this doesnt work would be helpful, Thanks!
